# llvm opt -always-inline pass doesn't inline

Tags: llvm, inline

I have the following function definition of SyS_sendto inside the (human readable) LLVM bitcode file Input.ll:

```
; Function Attrs: alwaysinline noredzone nounwind
define i64 @SyS_sendto(
i64 %fd, i64 %buff, i64 %len, i64 %flags, i64 %addr, i64 %addr_len) #0 {
```

In the end of the this file, attributes #0 **contains the word alwaysinline**:

```
attributes #0 = { alwaysinline noredzone nounwind "less-precise-fpmad"="false" "no-frame-pointer-elim"="false" "no-frame-pointer-elim-non-leaf" "no-infs-fp-math"="false" "no-nans-fp-math"="false" "stack-protector-buffer-size"="8" "unsafe-fp-math"="false" "use-soft-float"="false" }
```

Somewhere in Input.ll there is a call to SyS_sendto that **should be inlined
in the opt pass -always-inline**:

```
; Function Attrs: noredzone nounwind
define i64 @GO(i64 %fd, i64 %buff, i64 %len, i64 %flags) #0 {
  %1 = trunc i64 %fd to i32
  %2 = inttoptr i64 %buff to i8*
  %3 = trunc i64 %flags to i32
  %4 = tail call i64 bitcast
  (i64 (i64, i64, i64, i64, i64, i64)*
      @SyS_sendto to i64
          (i32, i8*, i64, i32, %struct.sockaddr*, i32)*)
          (i32 %1,
           i8* %2,
           i64 %len,
           i32 %3,
           %struct.sockaddr* null,
           i32 0) #0
  ret i64 %4
}
```

I run:

```
llvm-as -o=Input.bc Input.ll
opt -always-inline Input.bc -o InlinedInput.bc
llvm-dis -o=InlinedInput.ll InlinedInput.bc
```

But GO has **not** changed, and I see the call to SyS_sendto in InputInlined.ll too ... it was **not** inlined:

```
; Function Attrs: noredzone nounwind
define i64 @GO(i64 %fd, i64 %buff, i64 %len, i64 %flags) #0 {
  %1 = trunc i64 %fd to i32
  %2 = inttoptr i64 %buff to i8*
  %3 = trunc i64 %flags to i32
  %4 = tail call i64 bitcast
  (i64 (i64, i64, i64, i64, i64, i64)*
      @SyS_sendto to i64
          (i32, i8*, i64, i32, %struct.sockaddr*, i32)*)
          (i32 %1,
           i8* %2,
           i64 %len,
           i32 %3,
           %struct.sockaddr* null,
           i32 0) #0
  ret i64 %4
}
```

Any help is very much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A call to `@SyS_sendto` in your example is an instance of an indirect call (due to `bitcast` expression), and LLVM currently [does not support](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2015-January/080158.html) inlining these.

You can follow [the discussion on the mailing list](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2015-January/080158.html) (2015) or check in [the source code](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/90e60b5e9996dd85482e480f6d952bc6782d062b/lib/Transforms/IPO/Inliner.cpp#L534-L536).